# Moving array internal pointer exceeding maximum execution time

Tags: php, arrays, calendar

I'm trying to build a calendar system that would show 3 mini-calendar months. Last month, this month, and next month.

The code below is supposed to simply move the array pointer to the current month. I thought it was working Friday (September 28), but this morning (October 1) it causes the following error in the log: 
`PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded`

I doubt that it being a new month has anything to do with it, but I'm grasping for ideas. I'm hoping someone can see what I'm doing wrong here, because it all looks correct to me.

```
$thisMonth = date('m', time());

$arrMonths = array('01' => 'January', '02' => 'February', '03' => 'March', '04' => 'April', 
                    '05' => 'May', '06' => 'June', '07' => 'July', '08' => 'August', 
                    '09' => 'September', '10' => 'October', '11' => 'November', '12' => 'December');

while (key($arrMonths) !== $thisMonth) 
    next($arrMonths);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're using the strict comparison operator:

```
while (key($arrMonths) !== $thisMonth) 
    next($arrMonths);
```

`!==` is trying to match both the type and the content of your keys; in this case, because you've declared them with single quotes, your keys are strings. It's failing the type comparison (you're comparing a string with an integer) so it's going into an infinite loop.

To fix it, just use the looser comparison operator:

```
while (key($arrMonths) != $thisMonth) 
    next($arrMonths);
```

Thanks to @MiDo - I actually got this wrong:

```
the return value of date('m', time()); is a string and the keys are integers when they are >= 10.
```

Comment: Actually the return value of `date('m', time());` is a string and the keys are integers when they are >= 10. Would have said it the other way around, but that's what `var_dump` tells me. Loosening the comparison operator is still the right answer though.

Comment: Huh. That's what I get when I don't var_dump everything. I'll edit the changes in - thank you!

Comment: This would explain why it worked Friday, when the key was '09'. Thank you @MiDo.

And Thank You @andrewsi! Now that you point that out it makes perfect sense.

Comment: I wonder now what if I want the key `10` to be a string not an integer? But that's a rather theoretical and definetely another question...

Comment: @MiDo - to a great extent, it doesn't matter what you choose, especially if you're using the loose comparison operator. On the other hand, if you're using zero-padded numbers for the indexes, you need to store those as strings (as they'll be treated by PHP as octal if you leave them as integers, and 08 and 09 don't work at all in that case)